# In angular, is it possible inside the template to create a copy object?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a code similiar to this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
   <my-comp [CurrentHero]="hero"></mycomp>
</ng-container>
```

Now, in my application heroes array never change reference, just update his own values.

So, also "hero" never has a new reference.

But, i want that the component "my-comp" to be with OnPush strategy. So i need that @Input CurrentHero will have every time new reference, which not happend.

Is there a possibility to copy inside the tenplate the hero to be a new refernce?

Something like:

```html
<my-comp [CurrentHero]="{...hero}" ></my-comp>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that would be an anti-pattern if you are going with immutability.

What you should do is that when you are changing value of heroes, you should always return new object to `heroes` variable.

I don't know how you change values of `heroes` individual properties, but if you go like this

```js
changingHeroes() {
  let newHeroes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.heroes));

  newHeroes[0].something = 123;

  this.heroes = newHeroes;
}
```

Notice `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.heroes))` this is to do a deep copy of the object. Spreading it like `{...this.heroes}` will persist old references to every individual object in that array.

Comment: so i understand its not possible to do this from the template, right?

Comment: While it would be convenient to do so, it is not allowed and is detected as syntax error if you try it. But you can make method that does that and returns it if you dont want to go with my answer solution. What ever suits you better